# How to listen all changes in form with selects and inputs?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have form with selects and inputs, I need to make some actions `onchange` and `onkeyup`.
For now the following code

```
var $mainSearchForm = $('.form');
$mainSearchForm.on('change keyup', 'select input', function () {
  var infoForm = $mainSearchForm.serialize();
  var route = $('.form--url select').val();
  $('.btn').attr('href', route + '?' + infoForm);
});
```

How can I do it?
The example doesn't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select input` looks for `input` elements *inside* `select`. You just need to add a comma to separate them:

```
$mainSearchForm.on('change keyup', 'select, input', fn);
```

Alternatively you could use the `:input` selector to match all available form elements:

```
$mainSearchForm.on('change keyup', ':input', fn)
```